# Galaxy Tab S5E and multiple SD cards

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-tab

I got a Galaxy Tab S5E today to use as a photo editor. This is the 64gb version so I grabbed a micro SD card and put into it. A 128gb card. The card and tablet work together as expected.

I also grabbed a USB C card reader to plug in my camera SD cards on the go.

The issue I'm having is that the usb card reader is not working unless I remove the micro SD card and vice versa.

Is there any way to fix this?

The card reader doesn't registers as an SD card. It registers as a "usb mass storage device" so I'm not sure why there would be any type of conflict.